# How can I fix the following problem regarding the variable?

Tags: java, cloudsim

I have a class and inside it there is a baseDir variable which has been defined as follows:

```
public class experiment {
    for (int exp = 0; exp < experimentCnt; exp++) {
        String dirString = config.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + df.format(new Date());
        String baseDir = new File(homeDir + "/" + dirString).getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Running simulation: " + dirString);

        setCurrentDirectory(baseDir);

        PrintWriter paramsLog = null;

        try {
            paramsLog = new PrintWriter(
                 new File("experimentParams.log").getAbsoluteFile(), "UTF-8");
            paramsLog.println(params);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now, I want to use that baseDir variable in another class. How can I make it accessible?

Comment: You cannot have a for loop directly inside a class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of making a new variable inside your function, you should just make a public variable outside of your function.

```
public class experiment {

public String baseDir;

    for (int exp = 0; exp < experimentCnt; exp++) {
        String dirString = config.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + df.format(new Date());
        baseDir = new File(homeDir + "/" + dirString).getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Running simulation: " + dirString);

        setCurrentDirectory(baseDir);

        PrintWriter paramsLog = null;

        try {
            paramsLog = new PrintWriter(
                 new File("experimentParams.log").getAbsoluteFile(), "UTF-8");
            paramsLog.println(params);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```